# Unity frozen during upgrade from 12.10 to 13.04

Tags: 12.10, upgrade, 13.04

I started the upgrade process, and sometime around the "installing" step, Unity froze. The hard drive light is on, so I don't want to reboot it, but I also can't do anything at the moment. Is this normal? What should I do?

Update: It's been over an hour now. I'm going to download the ISO on another machine, and if it's still frozen when that finishes, I'll `sudo reboot` it and install the new version from a flash drive. Unless someone knows a better solution...

Answer (score 0):

I've been getting occasional compositor lockups with my Intel graphics -- apparently they're right on the verge of fixing it. If you have ssh installed, you can try to hop into your machine that way from another one you have on hand ... though I recognize that's a bit complicated for most users.

Comment: I'd considered doing something like that, but I'm not sure what I'd actually do after connecting since it's upgrading. I'm afraid if I restart Unity or reboot the whole machine, it'll mess something up.